Infinity Indexing Loop in PhpStorm
I am having trouble searching through my file as the indexing keeps looping.
Stop it but it seems like it is not possible according to PhpStorm docs.
The status bar shows the progress of the indexing process: Background Tasks dialog.
Scanning files to index and Updating indexes.

Your idea.log should give some hints on what is going on... Anyway: 1) Make sure all plugins are up-to-date 2) Please use File | Invalidate caches..., restart the IDE and see how it goes 3) Where the project is located (local disk, WSL, network share etc)? 4) Do you have multiple Composer files in a project?


Other than that: go through tickets here, you may spot one that matches your conditions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=infinite%20indexing

